# Python - ¿Pylatex encabezado?

Tags: python, pdf

Actualmente estoy realizando un archivo.txt con ayuda de Python, para después transformarlo en un archivo PDF usando PyLaTeX. Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
from pylatex import Document, PageStyle, LineBreak, Section, Subsection, Math, Alignat, LargeText, Center, MediumText
from pylatex.utils import bold, italic, NoEscape
import re
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp


TituloPDF="Ejercicio 001"
archivotxt = "%s.txt"% TituloPDF
texto = open(archivotxt,"w")

x = sp.Symbol('x', real=True)
y = sp.Symbol('y', real=True)

MatrizCoef=[y-x*y+1-x,-x*y]
g=0

texto.write("\\text{Para la ecuación diferencial:} \r")
texto.write("\\left({%s}\\right)dy = \\left({%s}\\right)dx \r"%(sp.latex(MatrizCoef[0]),sp.latex(MatrizCoef[1])))

texto.close()

class Math_LaTeX ():
    def __init__(self, doc):
        #---Inicializamos---
        self.doc = doc

        #---De aqui sacamos las ecuaciones del archivo .txt---
        equations = self.Read()

        #---Creamos el documento Latex---
        self.Create(equations)

        #---Creamos el PDF---
        self.doc.generate_pdf(filepath = TituloPDF, clean_tex = True, compiler = 'pdflatex')

    def Read(self):
        data = open(archivotxt, 'rt')
        equations = data.readlines()
        eqs = []
        for eq in equations:
            eqs.append(' '.join([line.strip() for line in eq.strip().splitlines()]))
        return eqs

    def Create(self, equations): 
        for eq in equations:
            with self.doc.create(Alignat(numbering = False, escape = False)) as math_eq:
                math_eq.append(eq)        


geometry_options = {
        "head": "0.5cm",
        "left": "0.5cm",
        "right": "0.5cm",
        "bottom": "2.5cm"
        }
doc = Document(geometry_options = geometry_options, inputenc = 'utf8')
Math_LaTeX(doc)
```

Eh trabajado bien con el, sin embargo quisiera poder personalizar el PDF entregado, actualmente esta es la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El margen en la parte superior es demasiado, ademas de que me gustaría poder agregar un encabezado, en resumidas cuentas así (Hecho en word):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El margen superior es adecuado, y tiene un encabezado que aparecen en todas las paginas que así requiera mi ejercicio.

También me gustaría que dicho encabezado se pueda cambiar cuando se introduzca un nuevo ejercicio o ejemplo.

Eh leído la documentación de PyLaTeX, pero no se me ocurre una forma de incluirlo todo en un solo código. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.